# In Swift, should you use built in get/set for properties or make getter/setter methods?

Tags: swift

When making a class in Swift, is it best to use the built-in get/set keywords for computed properties (see computed properties https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html) or use getter/setter methods?

I think using getter/setter methods rather than the get/set keywords can be helpful when getting/setting something can throw an error (I don't believe you can do `get throws { }`––I just tried it and Xcode expected '{' to start getter definition):

```
    func getData() throws -> [[HKSample]] {
        if self.hasData() {
            return self.data
        } else {
            throw BaseError.noData
        }
    }
```

Why shouldn't you exclusively make getter and/or setter class methods? Why shouldn't you exclusively use the get/set keywords except when you need to throw an error (I'm sure there are more use cases for methods than throwing an error)?  I don't understand the point of using the get/set keywords, especially when applying encapsulation principles to your code. Here's another example of the difference of the two where we're trying to calculate volume of a rectangular prism––is this:

```
    var volume: Double {
        return width * height * depth
    }
```

more favorable than this (or is it just a choice of style?):

```
    func getVolume() -> Double {
        return self.width * self.height * self.depth
    }
```

Comment: You are asking many questions at once and questions that are broad and/or opinionated. Maybe the best answer to all the questions are: _it depends_

Comment: " I don't understand the point of using the get/set keywords, especially when applying encapsulation principles to your code" I don't understand exactly what this part is referring to, but if it's the misconception that getter/setter methods are needed in Swift for encapsulation, then it's just that, a misconception. See my article here: https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Stop%20writing%20getters%20and%20setters%20in%20Swift.md

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica this was exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica in regards to the link you set, is there any official Swift documentation/info I can read to verify this/use as another reference? I've checked the Properties and Access Control sections in the Swift docs but they aren't this descriptive.

Comment: @JackA It depends on what part you're looking to verify, exactly. If it's the fact that all stored properties are computed properties, you can read about that in the [Library Evolution doc](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/LibraryEvolution.rst#id3). "Changing from a stored property to a computed property, or vice versa, as long as a previously ABI-public setter is not removed." It's also something that you can observe for yourself by making a Swift library, linking to it, editing the stored property into a computed one, and seeing that it doesn't break the ABI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed properties conventionally carry an implication that have constant time complexity. For example, `Array.first` and `Array.last` are computed properties, whereas `Array.min()` and `Array.max()` are functions.

As you've noticed, computed properties can't `throw`, so that sometimes forces your hand and makes you have to pick functions, even where computed properties would otherwise be more appropriate.

Comment: That implication is for people who don't like to learn things. There's `Complexity` available in structured documentation.

Comment: @Jessy Documentation is completely irrelevant when you're skimming over reading some code. You're not going to look up the docs of every single property access, fn call, etc. To prevent "gotchas", you don't put expensive operations behind computed properties. Saying "Oh well technically the documentation states that this computed property actually blocks on a network call" isn't justified; it's just bad API design.

Comment: I stand by what I said. You have some preconceived notion about `()`, but all having that does is make nouns look like verbs.

Comment: @Jessy It's not just me, that's been convention since ObjC introduced properties. It's the same in [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#functions-vs-properties), and in [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms229054(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) ("use a method rather than a property when... The operation has a significant and observable side effect"). See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/304077/109689 for more referneces. TL;DR: It's a **very** well established convention.

Comment: I know how well it's established. But that's only because old people didn't have computed properties when they weren't old, and so can't easily comprehend that computed properties require computation. I feel for them, but it's an IDE's job to help us all with this. It's not right to name something e.g. `max()` instead of `max` because C didn't support the latter.

Comment: "I feel for them, but it's an IDE's job to help us all with this" How do you suggest an IDE help with expressing expensive parts of computation? Keep in mind of course, that an ever-increasing amount of code-reading happens outside the IDE, on uncontrolled third party platforms like Github, GitLab, BitBucket, StackOverflow, etc.